# is there a way NicEditor be on a subfolder and not outside the demo page folder?

Tags: php

Hello I just want to know if I can put it on a subfolder instead ? When I tried to put it on subfolder or within the same folder of my page, it displays normal textare. But whenever I put it outside the folder it works fine.

Just asking for convenience.

Or if there is already an answer please tell me.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you put `NicEditor` in subfolder then you have to give subfolder's path for `NicEditor`.